# Jordan's curve theorem for embedded surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that a version of Jordan's curve  theorem hold on surfaces but I need a specific reference that states a statement (or can be derived from that statement) : Any simple closed curve on an embedded topological disk necessarily bounds a disk. Any such reference is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't it follow directly from Jordan-Schoenflies theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generalization

[image]

(Hatcher-pag.178) is known as *Generalized Jordan Curve Theorem*.

In particular this is true for any orientable surface with the same homology of $S^2$.